# How common is it for law schools to start by "smashing" the way a student currently thinks entering school?

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom

Scope: United States (and/or other Common Law Practicing Countries)

I spoke to a lawyer recently and she told me when students start in law school, the way they "currently think" is significantly berated, "put down", set aside, etc.  The old TV series Paper Chase highlights this kind of situation.  As far as I know, IF this is true, this is fairly unique to law, as a graduate type of degree.

So I'm wondering for those that are lawyers, or know first hand, e.g. via a loved one attending law school, how much is a person's initial or current way of thinking, "smashed", put down, or berated in law school? And if so, how long did this last?  1 week?  The whole 1st year?  Or longer ... 2 years?

And I'm going to ask too, since I haven't found this discussed much on the web:  is it seen as "you don't got the stuff", if you speak up about being berated, and so people don't tend to talk about this (being berated)?

--------------------- WHY I ASK THIS QUESTION --------------

Having a recent brutal ongoing experience with the criminal justice system (false  evidence put against me), I have had the (unfortunate) need to deeply examine it, on basic principle.  And I find, it is enormously off on basic principle, however the goal of this question is not to discuss that, but to understand how this is possible.  So, let's ask something basic:

If Peter hurts Paul, and I ask/seek anything OTHER from Peter than that he makes amends to Paul, am i then asking him to become my victim?

I find this is fully true, and I find the U.S. justice system is not "for the people" in terms of primarily making amends or to make whole the one that is hurt.  So Peter might very reasonably expect that I make demands that he make Paul whole, but he will rightly vehemently object, if I try to make him my victim.  "Two wrongs don't make a right."  Wholeness or amends, is the answer.  As children we were taught, if we harm another child, we have to make it up to them. The "justice" system is not at all about learning the whole story, and generally not about making amends, bringing wholeness.  Instead it (criminal in particular) looks to see if it can take some narrow slice of the actual event, prove guilt, and then make "you" it's victim.

Comment: I would suggest cutting the second half of the question (below "why I ask this question") because it doesn't make much sense and doesn't seem on topic now that the question has been moved here from law.SE.

Comment: This is an old stereotype of law schools, as essentially making students "unlearn" ethics and morality, replacing it with an amoral devotion to winning the case or whatever. It may be kind of interesting to know how true it is.

Comment: I wouldn't say 'berated', but education in many other fields also requires a student to learn how to think differently. In fact, I'd argue that's a large portion of what education is about.

Comment: This is yet another statement disguised as a question meant to push some alt-reality view and/or attempt to settle some score against foes real or imaginary.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't been to law school, but it sounds like this might be a description of the [Socratic method](https://lawschooltoolbox.com/ahead-of-the-curve-what-is-the-socratic-method/).  Searching Google for "Socratic method law school" shows lots of articles asserting that this was traditionally a common method of instruction in law schools, throughout the course of study, though it has become less common in the past couple of decades.

In principle, the idea is that students are asked challenging questions, to force them to carefully examine their thinking and help them find errors.  The purpose of the method isn't to "smash" the students ideas or to "berate" them, though I wouldn't be surprised if this line is sometimes crossed in practice.  It's also quite likely that students would sometimes *feel* berated by such questioning, even if that is not the original intent.  Those are certainly valid concerns.

Comment: This is about right. One time I was "on call" - this particular professor's way of saying the above-mentioned Socratic questioning was aimed directly at me - for more than 45 minutes of an hour-and-twenty minute class. It was rough. There was one professor who honestly delighted in humiliating students who have a wrong answer. Generally, though, those are outlier cases that everyone, of course, remembers more vividly for obvious reasons. Majority of profs take volunteers to answer questions and engage in some limited cold-calling.